# Why is my MVC Web Application timezone not setting correctly in Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, kendo-ui

I'm having problems with Azure when I upload my web application, at least, I think it's Azure.  My application uses `en-GB` globalization which I have set in the `web.config`.  Since I used KendoUI widgets, it's critical that this timezone is set to ensure the dates are correctly formatted.

Locally my application works fine, when I upload it to Azure it reverts to a US time format which is breaking a lot of the functionality.

At the moment my timezone is set in the `web.config` and in the layout using KendoUI's global script tag as devlivered by their CDN.

**Web.Config**

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"></globalization>
</system.web>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/cultures/kendo.culture.en-GB.min.js"></script>
<script>$(function () { kendo.culture("en-GB"); })</script>
```

I understand from searching that you can set your application in Azure to use specific time zones.

**Azure/Application Settings**

```
WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE | GMT Standard Time
```

I took the Azure timezone from the [list of zones consumed by Azure](https://jackstromberg.com/2017/01/list-of-time-zones-consumed-by-azure/)

> Note: My web app is also stored on UK West Servers on Azure

Yet, with all the above in place, I'm still getting US date format as soon as my application is on Azure.  Is there something I've missed or is my Azure setting perhaps incorrect?

Comment: I'm afraid using globalization settings for timezone info is not the right approach. `en-US` would not be resolvable, since the USA hast 4 time zones to my knowledge. Furthermore, what about an American settings his culture to en-US while working from Japan? So the first question would be: Are your dates stored as UTC?

Comment: Also, are we actually talking about timezones or just globalization / localization?